# Authenticate user application with IAM services

Tags: c#, identity-management

a c# windows application give privilege to users with a specific profile in its database. The application does not handle user and password but get the username of the authetcated user in Windows session.

They asked me to authenticate the user by a IAM service such as Microsoft IAM. But I'm a bit confused. It means that I have to ask username and password to user and verify them with IAM? I don't want to store in my db password.

I cannot figure how to use an external IAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you will not need to deal with passwords.

In short, your application will need to display a mini browser window (WebControl, WebView, etc.) where the IAM provider's login screen is displayed. Users provide their credentials directly to that login screen. Your application never touches those credentials and only receives the valid tokens afterwards from which it can get information like unique user ID, email address, etc.

Check out this WPF tutorial from one of the best IAM providers, auth0 (disclaimer: I'm not affiliated with auth0 in any way).
https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/wpf-winforms/01-login
You can sign up for a free trial account to quickly try it out.

Side note: This method is not entirely safe from abuse as your malicious application could intercept key strokes as users type in their credentials into the IAM login page (since it is hosted within your application's process).